# Change the width and height of a pseudo element with content

Tags: css, icons

I insert an icon this way

```
.me-icon-supericon:before {
    content: "\67";
}
```

and I'm trying to make it bigger. I tried to make it (display:inline-block) but it doesn't work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using custom font icon try font-size property...